# Converting data.frame with coordinates variable into sf object with geometry

Tags: r, coordinates, geospatial, spatial

My `data.frame` contains two `numeric` variables called `g_lat` and `g_long` that represent the geographic coordinate of the

observations. It looks like this:

| variable 1 | g_lat | g_long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 320000 | -34.23000 | 19.42833 |
| 600000 | 16.10000 | -22.80000 |

How can I convert this `data.frame` in a `sf`-object, where the variables `g_lat;g_long` are treated as the geometry column list?

I tried with the `st_as_sf` function, but an error occurs: `only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts`

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which columns are the coordinates:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(320000, 600000),
                 g_lat = c(-34.23000, 16.10000),
                 g_long = c(19.42833, -22.80000))

df_coord <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c(2:3))
```

Comment: Ok, it worked. Now the dataframe has a geometry column list. However, I am still not able to transform its coordinates, becaue when I use `st_transform`, specifying the crs 4326,  `cannot transform sfc object with missing crs`

Comment: This was awhile ago, perhaps you found this. For objects without a set `crs` use `st_crs(x) <- 4326` instead of transforming.